# Pass variable in url from views.py

Tags: python, django, django-views

Normally when passing a variable in templates you would do this:

```
{% url 'sw_app:test_editor' code=mycode %}
```

However, how can I do the same thing in my `views.py`?

I tried:

```
def go_to_test_editor(code):
    return reverse('sw_app:test_editor', code)
```

Says:

```
 No module named 'vQ6SMpo'
 # 'vQ6SMpo' is the code passed
```

And:

```
def go_to_test_editor(code):
    return reverse('sw_app:test_editor',code=code)
```

Says:

```
reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'code'
```

I'm fairly new in Django. Thanks a lot!

Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `args` to `reverse` like following.

```
reverse('sw_app:test_editor', args=[code])
```

To know more [visit the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/).

Comment: It returned `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: What is the path in urls.py file for it?

Comment: `path('test_editor/<str:code>', views.test_editor, name = 'test_editor'),`

Comment: It should just work, what is traceback of the error?

Comment: The error is not for `reverse`, it is related to the response that `views.test_editor` is returning. Can you add the definition of `views.test_editor` too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222655/discussion-between-md-nahidur-rahman-and-dran-dev).